# Can't seem to use PHP Namespaces correctly

Tags: php, namespaces

I am trying to setup my *autoloader* as suggested by the top comment in the official [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php#92514)

My test environment follows.

**C:\www\autoload.php** (setup as advised in top comment)

```
<?php 

spl_autoload_extensions(".php");
spl_autoload_register();
```

**C:\www\Car\Bmw.php**

```
<?php
namespace Car\Bmw;

class Bmw { var $v = 'Hello I am Class : Bmw'; }
```

**C:\www\Bike\Suzuki.php**

```
<?php
namespace Bike\Suzuki;

class Suzuki { var $v = 'Hello I am Class : Suzuki'; }
```

**C:\www\index.php**

```
<?php
use Car\Bmw;

include 'autoload.php';

$Obj = new Bmw();
var_dump($Obj);
```

I have tried some variations such as

- Defining include path in *autoloader* with set_include_path('C:\www\');
- Removing Bmw/Suzuki string from namespace/use or applying in one and not the other

Throughout these trials I have gotten numerous errors such as

```
Fatal error: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement in the script in C:\www\Car\Bmw.php on line 3
```

or

```
Fatal error: spl_autoload(): Class Car\Bmw could not be loaded in C:\www\index.php on line 8
```

If you are wondering why I want to use this setup please visit the link I gave earlier and read the top comment : [Linked again here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php#92514)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you paste everyting before the namespace line in Bmw.php?

Comment: @Maerlyn Updated my original post accordingly.

Comment: Make sure there is no whitespace/BOM in your file before the `<?php`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat It seems there was some whitespace, I have removed it now but still get Class Car\Bmw could not be loaded...
Edit : Updated my original post with no whitespace at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating these two classes:

- `Car\Bmw\Bmw`
- `Bike\Suzuki\Suzuki`

You'll need to modify your namespace declarations to be simply `Car` and `Bike` like this:

```
<?php

namespace Car;

class Bmw { /* */ }
```

Comment: Thanks it works now, I must have somehow skipped over this when I was trying all sorts of random variations.